# Cant seem to select the max value of WELL_CMPLTN_ID

Tags: sql, oracle, join, max, greatest-n-per-group

```
SELECT w.well_id,
w.WELL_NR,
w.WELL_NM,
w.WELL_API_NR,
ws.WELL_SGMNT_SIDE_TRCK_CD,
wc.WELL_CMPLTN_CD,
wc.WELL_SGMNT_ID,
wc.WELL_CMPLTN_ID
FROM WELL W
JOIN WELL_SGMNT ws
ON ws.well_id=w.well_id
JOIN WELL_CMPLTN wc
ON ws.WELL_SGMNT_ID=wc.WELL_SGMNT_ID
WHERE w.well_id    ='13030';
```

the result for this query is as below, but i want to have select the max value of WELL_CMPLTN_ID.
[image]

Comment: max value among all rows or a group ?

Comment: What version of Oracle? Oracle 12 has a new feature, `fetch first|last` which does quick work of such tasks. In general it helps to state your Oracle version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT w.well_id,
w.WELL_NR,
w.WELL_NM,
w.WELL_API_NR,
ws.WELL_SGMNT_SIDE_TRCK_CD,
wc.WELL_CMPLTN_CD,
wc.WELL_SGMNT_ID,
wc.WELL_CMPLTN_ID
FROM WELL W
JOIN WELL_SGMNT ws
ON ws.well_id=w.well_id
JOIN WELL_CMPLTN wc
ON ws.WELL_SGMNT_ID=wc.WELL_SGMNT_ID
WHERE w.well_id ='13030' AND wc.WELL_CMPLTN_ID = 
(SELECT MAX(wc.WELL_CMPLTN_ID) 
    FROM WELL W
    JOIN WELL_SGMNT ws
    ON ws.well_id=w.well_id
    JOIN WELL_CMPLTN wc
    ON ws.WELL_SGMNT_ID=wc.WELL_SGMNT_ID
    WHERE w.well_id ='13030'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT w.well_id,
    w.WELL_NR,
    w.WELL_NM,
    w.WELL_API_NR,
    ws.WELL_SGMNT_SIDE_TRCK_CD,
    wc.WELL_CMPLTN_CD,
    wc.WELL_SGMNT_ID,
    wc.WELL_CMPLTN_ID
    FROM WELL W
    JOIN WELL_SGMNT ws
    ON ws.well_id=w.well_id
    JOIN WELL_CMPLTN wc
    ON ws.WELL_SGMNT_ID=wc.WELL_SGMNT_ID
    WHERE w.well_id    ='13030
    ORDER BY wc.WELL_CMPLTN_CD DESC
    )
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

I hope it helps!